# Is it terrible to manually COMMIT a transaction in a twisted runInteraction?

Tags: twisted

I have a daemon written in Twisted.  It's scope and function have quickly grown, and it needs to be rebuilt from the ground up to properly handle the current workload.

The daemon does this , within a runInteraction :

1. select a row ( in this case, grabbing a row from "useraccount" )
2. grab and process several API endpoints ( for that user )
3. insert the data from the API endpoints
4. update the db record form the original row as "successfully updated"

The amount of activity occurring in steps 2 & 3 has steadily grown to where this needs to be refactored into multiple runInteractions and some additional database logging.

I'm currently rewriting this, but it's going to take a few days to get into production.

Until I get to that point, is it terrible to manually call a "COMMIT;ROLLBACK;" on the transaction's cursor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exact database you're using, but yeah, it's probably bad, although not terrible.  By issuing a COMMIT;ROLLBACK as SQL rather than Python method calls, you are probably messing up your underlying database library's idea of what transaction you're in.  Mostly though, keep in mind that your server might crash midway through doing this work; the whole point of `runInteraction` is that it gives you a transactional chunk of work that will all be performed at once.  If you don't care that your database might end up inconsistent, and it's working, then it's probably fine.

Comment: thanks.  within this "chunk" of work, everything is fine to commit - and there are no worries for potential inconsistencies.